# Angular 8 & Highcharts - how to show tooltip crosshairs

Tags: highcharts, angular8

I've installed [highcharts for angular](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) in my code and followed the [hello world example](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#hello-world-demo)
I'd like to add the [crosshairs tooltip](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.crosshairs) in my chart as in [this example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax) (the vertical line), so I modified the demo example options as follows:

```
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3],
      type: 'line'
    },
    {
      data: [3, 1, 2],
      type: 'line'
    }],
    tooltip: {
      crosshairs: true,
      shared: true
    }
  };
```

but I get the following error from the linter:

> Type '{ crosshairs: boolean; shared: true; }' is not assignable to type 'TooltipOptions'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'crosshairs' does not exist in type 'TooltipOptions'.ts(2322)
>   highcharts.d.ts(14729, 5): The expected type comes from property 'tooltip' which is declared here on type 'Options'

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tooltip.crosshairs`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.crosshairs) option is deprecated. Instead use [`xAxis.crosshair`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair) and/or [`yAxis.crosshair`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.crosshair):

```
chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3],
    type: 'line'
  }, {
    data: [3, 1, 2],
    type: 'line'
  }],
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  }
};
```

Or as a config object:

```
chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3],
    type: 'line'
  }, {
    data: [3, 1, 2],
    type: 'line'
  }],
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      // options here
      color: '#ff0000'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      // options here
      color: '#ffff00'
    }
  }
};
```